# ¿Como hacer una tabla pivotante?

Tags: sql, sql-server

¿Cómo hacer que **`Fecha`** aparezca en columnas? (Como si fuera una hora Excel)

Origen:

```
Nombre_Jugador   Asistencia   Fecha
Juan             A            01/01/2019
Juan             A            02/01/2019
Manolo           A            01/01/2019
```

Intención:
    SELECT Nombre_Jugador, Asistencia, Fecha
    FROM Fechas

```
    01/01/2019   02/01/2019   03/01/2019
JUan    A            A            F
Manolo  A            A            A
Jose    A            F            A
```

Comment: ¿Qué quieres que aparezca en cada columna de fecha? ¿Cuál es el rango de fecha? Te recomiendo que te des una vuelta por el [tour] para que veas como preguntar y sepas lo que es un [mcve].

Comment: Podrias mirar [answer]. No se entiende que necesitas ni queres. Tene en cuenta que una base de datos no es un sistema de vistas, solo escupe los datos que le pedis. El formato complejo lo tiene que dar el programa donde vos mostras los datos. Ahora, por favor apreta el boton [edit] y pone un ejemplo de lo que queres...

Comment: Ok.. ahi vamos mejor.. lo que vos queres es una tabla pivotante...

Comment: Creo que para mejorar tu pregunta deberías generar un escenario de prueba en donde te generes una tabla y agregues un par de datos, para posteriormente si explicar cual es el resultado que esperas obtener a partir de ese set de datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que necesitas en tu caso es "Pivotear" tus resultados. Para esto, existen diferentes técnicas, que, según la necesidad y tu entorno de trabajo (Versión de SQL, por ejemplo), podrían aplicar o no.

Te dejo un excelente artículo que describe muy bien las posibles alternativas e incluso evalua aspectos de rendimiento de cada una:

[Múltiples opciones para transponer filas en columnas](https://www.sqlshack.com/es/multiples-opciones-para-transponer-filas-en-columnas/)

De las opciones que presenta el artículo, creo que la más adaptable es la de SQL Dinámico (Por la posible `Expansión Horizontal`).

Para tu caso, quedaría (En esta alternativa), más o menos así:

```
Create table Jugadores (
    Nombre_Jugador varchar(200),
    Asistencia char(1),
    Fecha Date
)

insert into jugadores (Nombre_Jugador, Asistencia, Fecha) values('Juan', 'A', '01/01/2019')
insert into jugadores (Nombre_Jugador, Asistencia, Fecha) values('Juan', 'A', '02/01/2019')
insert into jugadores (Nombre_Jugador, Asistencia, Fecha) values('Manolo', 'A', '03/01/2019')

DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @columns = N'';
SELECT @columns+=N', p.'+QUOTENAME(Fecha)
FROM
(
    SELECT Fecha AS Fecha
    FROM [dbo].Jugadores AS p
    GROUP BY Fecha
) AS x;
SET @sql = N'
SELECT [Nombre_Jugador], '+STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '')+' FROM (
SELECT [Nombre_Jugador], [Asistencia] , Fecha
    FROM [dbo].[Jugadores]) AS j PIVOT (Max(Asistencia) FOR [Fecha] in 
       ('+STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')+')) AS p;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Estos serían los resultados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas grácias por ese gran aporte. Los que no sabemos tenemos que buscar gurús como tú.

Comment: ¿Esta respuesta solucionó tu problema, @Juan? Por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada si tu problema fue resuelto. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Comment: Gracias, eres un crack